# Laravel Foreign Key 'Trying to get property of non-object'

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I simply cannot wrap my head around Models.

I have two tables, `users` and `companies`. Users contains a column called `Company` which is a foreign key to the `companies` table. the companies table has two columns, an `ID` and `company_name` The value of `Company` under `users` references the id in `Companies`.

I am trying to get the value of company_name through the foreign key like so.

```
$user = User::find(1)->company->company_name;
```

My thought process, which may be wrong, is that this (depending  on if models are correct) should get the value of the Company column and then using that value, get the company_name from the Companies table.

My models look like so

User

```
public function company() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Company', 'company');
}
```

Company

```
protected $table = 'companies';
public function user() {
    return $this->hasOne('App\User');
}
```

All I continuously get is `Trying to get property of non-object`

I can see in the error log it gives that it's actually getting the company name too!

```
Trying to get property of non-object', 'C:\wamp\www\laravel\app\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php', '41', array('userid' => '1', 'usercompany' => '1', 'company' => 'BMW'))
```

But I don't understand where it's pullyig `userid` and `usercompany` from.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you're trying to get the property of a non-object, meaning that either `User::find(1)` or `company` is not an object. In the error message provided, it looks like one of the two is an array.

Look at your underlying database tables. Generally, the `id` is a protected field that is not returned in the result object. `usercompany` looks like the concatenated field to cross-reference the two tables (i.e. the foreign key).

Comment: I tried changing the foreign key to see if anything changes in that log and both the concatenated values stayed the same. It's kinda frustrating to see that it can see what I'm trying to grab. Laravels error messages don't help.

Comment: I'd run the following and see what it prints out for types: `var_dump(User::find(1))`. It will be a lot of data, but it will tell you what `company` is, whether an array or an object.

Comment: It tells me that 'company' => int 1. As part of arrays protected 'attributes' =>  and protected 'original' =>

Comment: So that's your issue. The `company` isn't an object. In your `company()` function, double check that the column in your underlying table is lowercase `company` and not `Company`

Comment: It most definitely is a lower case in the database table itself, so I'm not sure what's going on.